# Can you go up into pipes using Propeller Mario's Propeller jump?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-wii

I know this may seem obvious to many, but I have had trouble going up into pipes when I've used the Propeller Jump. Does using that move prevent you from going into a pipe, or am I simply not aiming well enough?

Comment: Are you pressing up as you're directly under the pipe?

Comment: Yes. Does it have to be dead center of the pipe?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: If you are jumping, be sure to actually hit the pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can, and there are at least a few pipes that are really only accessible in this way, particularly in single player. Here's a video example of one such pipe (**Note:** this does contain something of an exploration spoiler):

As I recall, you can simply hold the up button as you propel yourself upwards, so I would suggest trying that. That was typically pretty consistent for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't watch the video due to the spoilers, but I believe you.